# mySQL inner join with where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    mse_clients.Email
FROM    mse_clients
INNER JOIN mse_users ON mse_clients.`Franchise ID` = mse_users.`franchiseid`
WHERE   mse_users.id = '9';
```

Which returns no rows but it should return one.

```
SELECT * FROM mse_users WHERE id='9'
```

returns 1 row like it should.

And if I drop the where on the first query it returns all the rows.

How come this isn't working. Is it not possible to use a WHERE with an inner join?

[image]

Comment: Clearly, there is no row which satisfies both constraints. As an aside, note also that 9 is an integer, not a string.

Comment: @Strawberry see the image I added.

Comment: And including spaces in table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble

Comment: Could you add the columns of `mse_clients` and `mse_users` please? Of course you can use a WHERE condition with an INNER JOIN, but there is no row with matches all conditions. If you test the query with a LEFT JOIN perhaps you'll get a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Using where with inner join is truly possible

could be you have and integer id and not a string so try:

```
SELECT
mse_clients.Email
FROM    mse_clients
INNER JOIN mse_users ON mse_clients.`Franchise ID` = mse_users.`franchiseid`
WHERE   mse_users.id = 9;
```